# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type money

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.3, pg-restore, money

While importing I get this error:

> ```
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "transaction_details":
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type money: "$0.00"
> ```

`restore` completed, but the `transaction_details` table is empty.
This is Heroku's PostgreSQL Dump database.

PostgreSQL version on Heroku is 9.3.15 and the same on my system

The command I used:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U root -d database 577b86e3-8d96-4410-9b36-dd0f78cfe32f
```

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Honestly, don't use the `money` type. It's terrible. Switch to using `numeric`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The manual about the `money` type has advice for your case exactly:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html)

> Since the output of this data type is locale-sensitive, it might not
>   work to load `money` data into a database that has a different setting
>   of `lc_monetary`. To avoid problems, before restoring a dump into a new
>   database make sure `lc_monetary` has the same or equivalent value as in
>   the database that was dumped.

To check:

```
SHOW lc_monetary;
```

[The manual on `lc_monetary`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-MONETARY)

The example value in the error message (`'$0.00'`) would work with the default setting (among others):

```
lc_monetary = 'C';
```

You can set it in `postgresql.conf`, reload and try again ...

This peculiar behavior is one of the reasons why the `money` type is unpopular.

Comment: SHOW lc_monetary; output 'en_IN'

Comment: i see, when i tried same dump on cloud server based on USA region it works, lc_monetary is 'en_US.UTF-8' there